# How do I do matchTemplate by iterating all image in a folder?

Tags: java, opencv, template-matching

I want to match a character image that is cropped from an image with a set of template image of alphabets from another folder. I used template matching opencv to match them. what I can do now is this cropped image is mapped to the first image from the template folder and go to the next image for another image.

My question is how I can I iterate through the template folder so the cropped image will find the correct character to be match to. And is using this matchTemplate is correct way to use or I need to use other function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? Here I iterate over the directory and break the loop if the `template_matching()` returns true

```
import java.io.File;

 File dir = new File("folder-with-images");

 File[] files = dir.listFiles();

 for( int i=0; i < files.length; i++ ){ 
   String path = files[i].getAbsolutePath();

   // check the file type and work with jpg/png files
   if( path.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg") || path.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png") ) {

     PImage image = loadImage( path );

     // if template_match(image), break

   }
 }
}
```

Comment: you means that when it found the correct image then they do the template_matching, right?

Comment: No, I am checking the cropped images with the template